# How can I clone a progress view with an animation many times?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the createStackView() code to clone a custom progress bar I made but when I try and clone it by copy and pasting and creating createStackView2() the animation won't apply to the cloned progress bar. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    
    let percentageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00)
        return label
        
    }()
    let percentageLabel2: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00)
        return label
        
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        createStackView()
        createStackView2()
        
    }
    func createStackView2() {
        let trackLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let button2 = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button2.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button2.bounds.size.width
        button2.clipsToBounds = true
        button2.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap2), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button2)

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        trackLayer2.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        trackLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.82, green: 0.69, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        trackLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer2.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer2.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer2)
        
        shapeLayer2.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer2.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer2.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        shapeLayer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        
        view.addSubview(percentageLabel2)
        
        percentageLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
        percentageLabel2.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        
       //let stackView = UIStackView()
       //stackView.frame = view.bounds
       //view.addSubview(stackView)
    }
    func createStackView() {
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.center = view.center
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.82, green: 0.69, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.position = view.center
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer.position = view.center
        shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        
        view.addSubview(percentageLabel)
        
        percentageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
        percentageLabel.center = view.center
        
       //let stackView = UIStackView()
       //stackView.frame = view.bounds
       //view.addSubview(stackView)
    }
    var done = 0
    var toDo = 0
    
    @objc func handleTap() {
        toDo = 5
        if done < toDo {
            done += 1
        } else {
            done -= toDo
        }
        let percentage = CGFloat(done) / CGFloat(toDo)
        percentageLabel.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = percentage
        }
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
    @objc func handleTap2() {
        toDo = 5
        if done < toDo {
            done += 1
        } else {
            done -= toDo
        }
        let percentage2 = CGFloat(done) / CGFloat(toDo)
        percentageLabel2.text = "\(Int(percentage2 * 100))%"
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shapeLayer2.strokeEnd = percentage2
        }
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not making a stack view, that is just the messy code name. You should try the code out, what it does is updates the view, it does not add a new layer.

Comment: OK well I did try out the code. When I tap in the middle of a circle, it animates. Either circle. So it all seems to be working decently. So can you explain what the issue is that you are asking about?

Comment: Hmm, for me it will only animate the circle in the middle. What I am looking for is code that will allow me to replicate this button with animation through a singular function. Optimally I would like to use a function and it creates a separate button each time.

Comment: Sure, so just take the two sets of code that you've got for the two button/shape pairs, and refactor them into a single piece of code. Think about what's the same and what's different for them. That's totally standard procedure (DRY, don't repeat yourself).