# How can I repeat a function and change a variable each time?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to repeat the function createCircle() multiple times and each time I want to change the button.center value, how can I do this and still keep the animation for each circle? Currently when I try and repeat the variable by copying and pasting the function createCircle() with different positioning, my animation handleTap() will not work on the other circles.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    let percentageLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = ""
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 28)
        label.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00)
        return label
        
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        createCircle()
        
    }
    func createCircle() {
        let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.center = view.center
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTap), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: 50, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        
        trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.82, green: 0.69, blue: 0.52, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
        trackLayer.position = view.center
        view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
        
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 0.59, green: 0.42, blue: 0.23, alpha: 1.00).cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
        shapeLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        shapeLayer.position = view.center
        shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        
        view.addSubview(percentageLabel)
        
        percentageLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
        percentageLabel.center = view.center
    }
    var done = 0
    var toDo = 0
    
    @objc func handleTap() {
        toDo = 5
        if done < toDo {
            done += 1
        } else {
            done -= toDo
        }
        let percentage = CGFloat(done) / CGFloat(toDo)
        percentageLabel.text = "\(Int(percentage * 100))%"
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = percentage
        }
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change just a part of the body of the function in different calls you should use a parameter. As for the tap detection, I believe it happens in the view and not the layer (not sure).

Comment: In the case of the tap detection, it does effect the view not the later, how can I change it to effect a single circle?

Comment: For the detection, I believe this question may be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53041776/how-am-i-supposed-to-implement-pointinsidewith

Comment: I am not trying to give each circle it's own property. I would just like to be able to use the same function handleTap() on each circle individually. As you mentioned it seems to effect the view. For example when I click on one of three buttons that I print, the animation will only play on the button that was most recently called.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132657/how-can-i-clone-a-progress-view-with-an-animation-many-times ?

Comment: Matt it is similar code, but I am trying to figure out how I can call an animation to each individual circle. Currently my animation effects the entire view, but I would like to use it on one circle. Sorry if it seems sort of like a repeat, if stack overflow doesn't like that I will try not to do this in the future.